# Django - Differences in System date and Django Template Tag date

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a problem with dates in my system. I'm using CentOS6.

The problem is the following... I have differences in dates...

If I go to my Linux Console:

```
[andre@andre example]$ date
Tue Nov 22 23:57:10 WET 2011
```

If I go to Python Shell:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 22, 23, 50, 10, 146843)
```

And if I use a Template Tag from Django like this one:

```
{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
I got this: 22nd November 2011 17:52
```

This is a 6 hour difference. Can you give me a clue on how to solve this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's a mismatch between your [Django TIME_ZONE setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#time-zone) and your server time zone. If you want Django to use your server's time zone, set TIME_ZONE = None